# router.push remove param from url for ru language

Tags: next.js

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
....

const router = useRouter()
const { pathname, asPath, query } = router

const setLanguage = (nextLocale) => {
    router.push({ pathname, query }, asPath, {
      locale: nextLocale
    })
  }
```

Above you can see my function for language changing , below you can see my `next.config.js` file

```
module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en', 'ru'],
    defaultLocale: 'ru',
    localeDetection: false
  }
}
```

When I execute `setLanguage('ru')` it makes my path `localhost:3000`, when I execute `setLanguage('en')`, it makes `localhost:3000/en/`, how can I fix it , and make it works for `ru` same way as for `en` ?

And us I see , it doesn't matter `ru` it , or it will be other language  `defaultLocale: 'ru'` , matter

Comment: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/18419#discussioncomment-327128

Comment: how it helps me @brc-dd, could you explain in more details?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but don't you want the same thing as that feature request? By default whatever you set as the `defaultLocale` will be rendered as `/` instead of `/locale-name`. That feature request is asking that there should be an option to make all locales equivalent, i.e. each of them is rendered on separate `/locale-name` and `/` is redirected to `/default-locale-name`. The particular comment that I have linked to provides a workaround for now that may be helpful to you. PS: your `setLanguage('ru')` is making your path `localhost:3000` because of this particular issue.

Comment: oh , yes, sorry , you answer is relevant , thanks)

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to force default locale in the URL when clicking a link in Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66615874/how-to-force-default-locale-in-the-url-when-clicking-a-link-in-next-js)? It references the `Link` component, but the same logic can be applied to `next/router`.